# How to set the margin and padding of an ImageView?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, javafx-css

How to set the margin and the padding of an `<ImageView>`?

I did `fx-padding: 50px;` and `fx-margin: 50px;` but it doesn't work.

My code :

```
<ImageView style="fx-padding: 50px; fx-margin: 50px;"
    fitHeight="120" fitWidth="120" fx:id="image" onMousePressed="#mousePressed">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Plain CSS (inline 'style' too) does not use the 'fx-' prefix. Maybe just remove the 'fx-'?

Comment: @Rene This is JavaFX-flavored CSS, all properties are conventionally prefixed with `fx`.

Comment: I don't use JavaFX, but it seems (from [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)) [ImageView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#imageview) only has [Node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node) CSS properties, which has no `fx-padding` or `fx-margin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [property list of `ImageView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html); there is no such property or any property that would allow you to achieve a similar effect. You may be able to use the layout parameters of the parent layout to achieve the effect; If this is impossible; you need to wrap the `ImageView` in a layout that does permit this, e.g.:

```xml
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"> <!-- use the preferred size for max size constraints -->
    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="50" />
    </padding>
    <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="120" fitWidth="120" fx:id="image" onMousePressed="#mousePressed"/>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```